# How to use React.Context for event tracking

Tags: javascript, reactjs, analytics

I'm trying to create a generic event tracking component for my react app. My general idea was to have a global event listener that would use html attributes to track events and trigger events handlers (click, submit etc) based on the event that was fired. I wanted to use React.Context api to be able to track page level data to use for tracking purposes.

The problem I'm having is figuring out how to use React.Context api is in this use case. Here's the basic structure I figured I would be using:

index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import store from './lib/store'
import history from './lib/history'

import Login from './Containers/Login/Login'
import Logout from './Containers/Login/Logout'
import Hello from './Containers/Hello/Hello'
import AnalyticsProvider from './lib/tracking/AnalyticsProvider'

ReactDOM.render((
    <Provider store={store}>
        <AnalyticsProvider>
            <Router history={history}>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path={'/login'} component={Login}  />
                    <Route path={'/logout'} component={Logout} />
                    <Route path={'/hello'} component={Hello} />
            </Router>
        </AnalyticsProvider>
    </Provider>
), document.getElementById('root'))
```

lib/tracking/AnalyticsProvider.js

```
import React from 'react'

class AnalyticsProvider extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        _initClickHandler()
        _initSubmitHandler()
    }

    _initClickHandler = () => {
        window.addEventListener('click', _handleClick, false)
    }

    _initSubmitHandler = () => {
        window.addEventListener('submit', _handleSubmit, false)
    }

    _handleClick = () => {
        // Handle adding click event to analytics manager here
        console.log('Click Event fired')
    }

    _handleSubmit = () => {
     // Handle adding submit event to analytics manager here
        console.log('Submit event fired')
    }

    render = () => this.props.children
}

export default AnalyticsProvider
```

Containers/Hello/Hello
    import React from 'react'

```
class Hello extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
      this.state = {
          isHidden: true, 
          testData: 'Some sample data'
      }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="hello-component">
        { this.state.isHidden ? '' : 'Hellow'}
        <button data-analytics-name="TEST_HELLO" onClick={ () => this.setState({isHidden: !this.state.isHidden})) }>Toggle Hello</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

So, conceptually in the `_handleClick` method I want to be able to access context data from the Hello compoent when the 'Toggle Hello' button is clicked.

I can't figure out how to set up my components this way. Any thoughts? Or in general any better approaches to generic analytics capturing?

Answer (score 0):

What context data are you trying to access from Hello component? Is it `data-analyticsName`? You can easily access data attribute in `AnalyticsProvider` like so:

```
  _handleClick = e => {
    // Handle adding click event to analytics manager here
    if (e.target.dataset.analyticsName) {
      console.log(
        "Click event fired with data " + e.target.dataset.analyticsName
      );
    }
  };
```

Here is your code with some small changes: https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-spence-6fyu1

Comment: No, sorry should have added  more to my example. The html attribute was more to filter out the click events which should be used. I mean more in terms of being able to access any data that might exist in a component like hello. So, if I had a state object rather than creating html attributes for every state elment i wanted being able to access it via context. Does that make sense?

Comment: @bos570 sorry, I don't know how to extract data which is rendered in component. An alternative option would be to `JSON.stringify()` state object and pass it with data attribute like you pass `analyticsName`.